# Drawn TextView doesn't appear

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have this class for drawing text to a canvas. Nothing appears though when I draw text. Although the canvas can be drawn to because some other code works fine.

Is there something I'm missing? Also, it would be good to limit the width and height of the drawable area of the canvas too.

The context comes from the same view as the canvas.

```
public class GraphicsDroid
    {
        readonly Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas;
        readonly Context context;

        public GraphicsDroid(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas, Context context)
        {
            this.canvas = canvas;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void DrawText((Color?, Color) color, float fontSize, string text, float x, float y, float width, float height)
        {
            var textView = new TextView(context)
            {
                Text = text
            };

            textView.SetSingleLine(true);
            textView.Ellipsize = TruncateAt.End;
            textView.SetTextColor(color.Item2.ToAndroid());
            textView.TextSize = fontSize;
            textView.SetWidth((int) width);
            textView.SetHeight((int) height);

            if (color.Item1 is Color background)
            {
                textView.SetBackgroundColor(background.ToAndroid());
            }

            var saveCount = canvas.Save();

            try
            {
                canvas.Translate(x, y);

                textView.Draw(canvas);
            }
            finally
            {
                canvas.RestoreToCount(saveCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm hacking a 3rd party component.

Comment: ok, I will look into it - I reckon it would slow it down though. Also, I set the width and height and there's still no sign of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rendered the textview to a layout...

```
public void DrawText((Color?, Color) color, float fontSize, string text, float x, float y, float width, float height)
        {
            var layout = new LinearLayout(context);

            var textView = new TextView(context)
            {
                Text = text
            };

            textView.SetSingleLine(true);
            textView.Ellipsize = TruncateAt.End;
            textView.SetTextColor(color.Item2.ToAndroid());
            textView.TextSize = fontSize;
            textView.SetWidth((int) width);
            textView.SetHeight((int) height);

            if (color.Item1 is Color background)
            {
                textView.SetBackgroundColor(background.ToAndroid());
            }

            layout.AddView(textView);

            layout.Measure(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
            layout.Layout(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);

            var saveCount = canvas.Save();

            try
            {
                canvas.Translate(x, y);

                layout.Draw(canvas);
            }
            finally
            {
                canvas.RestoreToCount(saveCount);
            }
        }
```